# Passport cookie session not stored on nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, passport.js

I have been working on MERN stack application, I tried to create login module for my application, so I have used Google authentication in the server side using `passport.js`.

Every thing *working* good when I use *localhost*.

But, when my app running on AWS server, then `node.js` does not store my cookie session, so that passport `deserializeUser` is *not working*, and passport `serializeUser` is *working* good.

**Note:**
My react app is running on digital ocean server and my node app is running on AWS server.

API call in my react app:

```
axios.get(url,{withCredentials: true}).then((response) =>{
console.log('login:',response.data)
}).catch((e)=>{
console.log('error:',e)
 })
}
```

Session setting in my node app:

```
  router.use(cookieParser());
  router.use( session( { secret: 'keyboard cat',
  cookie: { maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 },
  resave: true, 
  saveUninitialized: false
  }
  )
  );
  router.use(passport.initialize());
  router.use(passport.session());
```

Comment: Can you add the errors you are getting?

Comment: i did not get any error , node does not store passport session, so that when i print  req.user  is shows undefined.

Comment: try printing req.session.user?

Comment: req.session.user undefined